# Sinatra/Rack params[] in before block

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I'm making a site using Sinatra, everything is going well, or was until I needed to access the `params[]` hash in the `before` block.

Basically, I'm trying to do this:

```
before do
  if params[:forum_id]
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    build_breadcrumbs(@forum.parents)
    # ... more code, snipped to keep it short
  end
end
```

But the thing is, I can't call the `params[]` hash in the `before` block, does anyone have any ideas?

The reason I'm putting this code in the `before` block is because I'd rather not have to go and put it in every one of my `get` and `post` blocks for every page.

Answer (score 6):

From the docs:

> Before filters are evaluated before each request within the same
>   context as the routes will be and can modify the request and response.

Since this happens before the actual request, you can't access the request parameters. What you can do is put the repetitive code into a method and call that in your route blocks.

Comment: Your post gave me an idea of trying `before '/f/:forum_id'` (plus other forum pages) and that worked. Thank you :).

Comment: Your welcome, glad it helped! :-) To mark your question as solved you can accept this answer by clicking the little tick mark under the votes count. That way other users know that you don't need any more help. Only do this if an answer solved your question though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true anymore. I just tested it. You can now access params in before {...}